# Github Jekyll add bootstrap progress-bars

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, github, jekyll, octopress

[My Github](https://github.com/xinqiu/xinqiu.github.io)

I'm noob.

I set this configuration, but didn't work.

I fork the [hpstr-jekyll-theme](https://github.com/mmistakes/hpstr-jekyll-theme)

It uses the octopress

I want to add progress-bar.

but it didn't work.

Comment: Can't you explain a little more what is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

> ## When testing locally leave blank
>
> ```
>   url: xinqiu.github.io
> ```

It should be added a blanckspace.